# Query to convert from datetime to date in zend framework 2 using table data gateway

Tags: php, date, zend-framework2

I just want to pull only date from a datetime column in zend framework 2. I have written this as follows -

```
$select->where->between('date(view_logs.date)', '2013-01-01', '2013-03-31');
```

to get the following result in query.

```
WHERE DATE(`view_logs`.`date`) BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-03-31'
```

But this is not working. Parenthesis and casting is not generated. Can anyone help me to write date casting in zend framework 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to use an expression there

```
$select->where->addPredicate(
    new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression("date(view_logs.date) BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-03-31'")
);
```

what error are you getting?

Comment: Not working. It shows- Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN '2013-03-01' AND '2013-03-31' . By getting sql string, I found column name(view_logs.date) is missing before BETWEEN in this way.

Comment: I got 2 more warning also. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql.php on line 123

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql.php on line 140

Comment: Are you using Predicate\Expression or the other one?
Maybe you will need to just skip using between predicate and use just an expression

Comment: updated answer, I think that should work, it's hard to do from memory without being able to test it ;)

Comment: Under ZF 2.1, it's actually much simpler, a plain old: $select->where( "DATE( view_lots.date ) BETWEEN 'x' and 'y'" ); would be fine.  Also, careful of the broken string in the answer above.  The string in the expression should be wrapped with double quotes in consideration of the single quotes within it.